# How to make a token bold+italic in VS TextMateRules

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown, textmate

In Visual Studio Code I edit markdown files.

In the editor the text marked `**bold**` is rendered **bold** and the one marked `*italic*` is rendered in *italic.* But the text marked `***bold and italic***` is rendered simply as *italic*.

I tried to put in `editor.tokenColorCustomizations.TextMateRules` the following rule:

```
{
  "scope": ["markup.italic.markdown", "markup.bold.markdown"],
  "settings": {
     "fontStyle": "italic",
     "fontWeight": "bold"
  }
}
```

But VSC complains that `fontWeight` does not exist in settings and `fontStyle` accepts either `bold` or `italic` but not a combination of the two.

Any idea?
Thanks!
mario

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works for me:

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
  "textMateRules": [
    {
      "scope": "markup.bold.markdown markup.italic.markdown",
      "settings": {
        // "foreground": "#00ff00",
        "fontStyle": "italic bold",
      }
    },
  ]
},
```

For some reason, the `markup.bold.markdown` needs to be listed first, before `markup.italic.markdown`.  Despite actually being listed second in the `Scopes` hover box.

I would consider that a bug unless someone has a good explanation.

Also note that your form:

```json
"scope": ["markup.italic.markdown", "markup.bold.markdown"],
```

treats the scopes as two separate scopes (because of the `,` separator it doesn't combine the scopes - they are treated as two separate scopes, so either one gets both bolded and italicized which I assume is not what you actually want.

Comment: Fantastic! It works. Thanks. So `editor.tokenColorCustomizations.TextMateRules` is really powerful, if only was better documented...