# VS Code: Is it possible to specify a token color customization that requires multiple scopes at once?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code allows users to [customize syntax highlighting colors for specific syntax](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_editor-syntax-highlighting) in `settings.json`. The most flexible way to do this is using the `"textMateRules"` property,
which is formatted something like this:

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
  "textMateRules": [{
    "scope": ["keyword.other", "keyword.control"],
    "settings": {
      "foreground": "#FF0000",
      "fontStyle": "bold"
    }
  }]
}
```

The problem with the above snippet is that it applies the selected styles to either `keyword.other` OR `keyword.control` scopes. **Is it possible to devise a `textMateRules` configuration that requires the `keyword.other` AND the `keyword.control` scopes?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/64836542/836330

Use this form:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
  "textMateRules": [{
    "scope": "keyword.other keyword.control",
    "settings": {
      "foreground": "#FF0000",
      "fontStyle": "bold"
    }
  }]
}
```

`"scope": "keyword.other keyword.control",   // note separated by a space, one string`

This form will require **BOTH** scopes to be present in order to be applied.